# LINQ How to define a default type for use with ElementAtOrDefault Operator

Tags: c#, linq, list

I very much like the sound of this ElementAtOrDefaultOperator for use with generic lists, but I cant figure out how to define a default type for my list of objects. From what I understand, the defaultvalue will be null if I have a list of objects as below, but I would like to return my own version of a default object with proper values. Here is what I mean:

```
ClassA {

string fieldA;
string fieldB;
ClassB fieldC;

//constructor

}

List<ClassA> myObjects = new List<ClassA>();

myObjects.Add( //new object )
myObjects.Add( //new object )
```

So I want to be able to do the following:

```
ClassA newObject = myObjects.ElementAtOrDefault(3);
```

And have newObject be a default type of ClassA that I define somewhere. I thought there might be a SetDefaultElement or some other method but I dont think it exists.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just write your own extension method:

```
static T ElementAtOrDefault<T>(this IList<T> list, int index, T @default)
{
    return index >= 0 && index < list.Count ? list[index] : @default;
}
```

and call:

```
var item = myObjects.ElementAtOrDefault(3, defaultItem);
```

Or if you want the default to be evaluated lazily, use a `Func<T>` for the default:

```
static T ElementAtOrDefault<T>(this IList<T> list, int index,
    Func<T> @default)
{
    return index >= 0 && index < list.Count ? list[index] : @default();
}
```

This form, for example, would allow you to use a pre-defined item (the first, for example):

```
var item = myObjects.ElementAtOrDefault(3, myObjects.First);
```

or more flexibly:

```
var item = myObjects.ElementAtOrDefault(3, () => myObjects[2]);
```

or

```
var item = myObjects.ElementAtOrDefault(3, () => new MyObject {...});
```

Comment: An appropriate overload could return default(T) as in the LINQ implementation.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - but that already exists in the non-overloaded, standard LINQ operator...

Comment: Really wonder why it's not already part of the framework. It's trivial but i don't want to add extension classes to inherited projects just for this overload.